# Compile error while trying to compile android app with ant

Tags: android, ant

I am trying to compile my android app in ant and I keep getting this message:

```
BUILD FAILED
K:\build.xml:359: aaptexec doesn't support the "basename" attribute
```

why does this happen? I am using the template from android sdk 4.

Thanks, Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, provide full ant output with stack trace. You're probably using mismatched sdk/target platform versions. This might cause use of unsupported build system features from your build.xml. Upgrade your sdk, and update build configuration with `android` tool:

`android update project --name <project_name> --target <target_ID>
--path <path_to_your_project>`

See http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/other-ide.html for `android` command details

Comment: Yea I did that already thanks the problem seems to be solved. and I was using the ant_rules file from my target platform I changed this to the main_ant_rules.xml in the tools folder I think this fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

Just had the same issue and resolved the problem by using the right ant build.xml, probably the one Google really maintains. It's located at android-sdk\tools\ant\main_rules.xml and resolves this issue.