# Android ant, error that if doesn't support the "condition" attribute

Tags: android, ant

I am using Ant to make APK file for Android project. When I am doing ant debug... I have the below error..

**ANDROID_HOME/tools/ant/build.xml:427: if doesn't support the "condition" attribute.**

The line 427 of build.xml file is **`<if condition="${project.is.test}">`**.

I have no ideas why I have this error.

If anyone experienced this, please give me any clues to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Found the solution... [Compile error while trying to compile android app with ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464461/compile-error-while-trying-to-compile-android-app-with-ant?rq=1)

need to make build.xml again.. :)

Comment: Quick sanity check: what version of ant are you using? (`ant -version`)?

Comment: I am using latest one.. 1.9.0..